# Object variable not set when inserting into database

Tags: asp.net, html, sql-server, vb.net

I've got probelm with inserting data into database.

```
Dim PostId As Object = DirectCast(Repeater1.FindControl("lblPostId"), Label)
```

I have to use Findcontrol, because the page can't find lblPostId automatically. Then I definy
InsertCommand and parameter like this:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Comments] ([CommentText], [UserName], [PostId]) VALUES (@CommentText, @UserName, @PostId)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = PostId.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Context.User.Identity.Name
        cmd.Parameters.Add("CommentText", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = text.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is m HTML, label is inside Repeater (binded by sqldatasource):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPostId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' />
```

But it return error, that *Object variable or with variable not set* on PostId parameter. I don't know why?
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim PostId As Object = DirectCast(Repeater1.FindControl("lblPostId"), Label)
```

should be

```
Dim PostId As Label = DirectCast(Repeater1.FindControl("lblPostId"), Label)
```

and, always add parameter in order they appear

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Comments] ([CommentText], [UserName], [PostId]) VALUES (@CommentText, @UserName, @PostId)"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommentText", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText).Value = text.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Context.User.Identity.Name
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(PostId.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I fixed it, but it still return in both variables (PostId, Text) is System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object...

Answer (score 1):

When you search a control inside a Repeater you should consider how many ItemsTemplate are showing up in you Repeater control.

The [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) method

> Searches the current naming container for a server control with the
>   specified id parameter

If your repeater returns 2 rows of data, then you have, inside the repeater, two 'naming containers', one for each row and they are represented by separate instances in the Items collection.

So your code to get the `lblPostID` should be the following

```
Dim PostId As Label = DirectCast(Repeater1.Items(0).FindControl("lblPostId"), Label)
```